# Как отследить наводку курсора мыши на консольное приложение C++

Tags: c++

Надо обработать события когда курсор находиться в консольном окне. Надо что-то на подобия функции  TrackMouseEvent только для консоли, то есть когда курсор в консольном окне должно выдавать True и на оборот когда выходит из него должно выдавать False.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Никак. Окно с текстом не принадлежит консольному приложению. Консольное приложение работает через стандартные потоки ввода-вывода. Как вариант, отслеживать https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/mouse-event-record-str

Comment: В общем случае никак. Надо понимать, что консольное приложение может запускаться и вовсе без консоли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <Windows.h>

bool IsInConsol(const HWND& hwnd,POINT& p)
{
    RECT aRect;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &aRect);
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    if (((p.y >= aRect.top) && (p.y <= aRect.bottom)) && ((p.x >= 
aRect.left) && (p.x <= aRect.right)))return true;
    return false;
}
```